# Drupal on uWamp won't start ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: apache, ssl, drupal, uwamp

I need your help. I try to make a website with Drupal in localhost, using uWamp. But everytime I try to access my site/index.php or just site/ , I get an error : ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I change the value of the 'port' field in settings.php but nothing to do, won't work. Any solutions?
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your uWAMP server running MySQL on port 3306? Could you check? Also check that your uWAMP webserver is running on the standard web port 80? Maybe it's localhost:8080 ?

It might be best to change your uWAMP MySQL port to 3307 and your apache port to 81 just in case some other apps are listening on that port.

Comment: I'm using 8080 for the webserver. How can I know wich port is used by mySQL?